# How to manage sessions in a REST service with Spring 3 MVC and Weblogic?

Tags: session, rest, spring-mvc, weblogic

I've read that [a REST service should be stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398584/how-to-manage-sessions-in-restful-wcf-service) but we're trying to implement a mobile service near to an existing web application, so we're trying to keep the same flow and be consistent.

Specifically:

> 1) login
>
> we check for the username and password, "create" a session and response with a sessionid

then

> 2) choose role passing the sessionid
>
> we store the role information in the session

and so on.

This is probably not the best approach but would be the simpler for our case.

Is this possible? How can I get the session with Spring/Weblogic?

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session is in one way a cache with a time out. You could use whirly cache. code.google.com/p/whirlycache/ when creating it can speicfy the time out and max number of items.

When you get a valid login, make a random number of 10 or more digits, make sure its not already there in the cache (if there then re create a random number ... meaning unique in the current cache).  [at login can also check number of items to make sure not reaching max - send alert if its near means you have more active users than anticipated or people are not logging out - maybe need another cache with key as active user ids so see if same person has not already got a active session, so reject if same user already has a session active, delete both on logout]

Now make your session object (a good idea is a lite user object with user id, security roles etc depending on your business requirements) and store it in the cache.

Now when other methods are called, they should accept a session id, check the cache if there is a matching session id key, get the user object and continue with validations and processing.

Comment: In the end I've resolved the problem "automagically", but I will mark this as answer. Thanks. : )

Comment: Basically the client that was using the service is keeping the sessione generated by the container (Weblogic in my case), so no need to do something strange. I already have a nice Spring session scoped bean (as you suggested) that is injected with all the properties. Something "magical" let's say.. lol