# How can we implement the Session Management and Authentication in WCF REST?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

We have a task to expose a WCF REST API where we wanted to implement the Session Management and Authentication of the Client. After googling I found that the Session Management is not possible with WebHttpBinding .

Is there any other mechanism to implement Session Management in WCF REST API ?

Comment: May be useful "How to Manage Sessions in Restful WCF Service" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398584/how-to-manage-sessions-in-restful-wcf-service