# How to implement Authentication and Authorization in WCF Restful Service

Tags: wcf, security, rest

I am trying to implement security for the WCF rest service which will be exposed over the net for consuming. Here are the requirements

#### Authorization for Service and Specific API's

> The service should authorize the partner and check if the partner has the access to the API which is called and i have multiple partners calling these restful APIs.

How do I authorize each of these partners for APIs in a centralized way?

#### Authentication for the User

> I need to perform Authentication for users in order to perform the Add,Delete operations.

How do I authenticate the users for specific APIs in centralized way.

Comment: I have to check if the partner is authorized to access specific APIs in my service. How to identify which method is called by the partner in a centralized way like a interceptor? i was looking at a way to identify the method in the interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following appraoch to implement the Authorization and Authentication fot the rest services.

Used the Custom Attribute which Implements the Attribute, IOperationBehavior, IParameterInspector

Here is the Implementation.

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior, IParameterInspector
{

    public SLCE.Operations Operation { get; set; }

    public bool IsAuthenticationRequired { get; set; }

    #region IOperationBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {           
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {

    }

    #endregion

    #region IParameterInspector Members

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {

    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        string publicKey = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];
        bool flag = AuthorizationHelper.CheckPartnerAuthorization(this.Operation, publicKey);
        if (!flag)
        {   
            LicensingValidationHelper.ThrowLicensingException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, SLCE.LicensingStatus.PartnerNotAuthorized.ToString());
        }
        else if(IsAuthenticationRequired)
        {
            string authenticationKey = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authentication"];
            bool isAuthenticated = AuthorizationHelper.CheckUserAuthentication(authenticationKey);

            if (!isAuthenticated)
            {
                LicensingValidationHelper.ThrowLicensingException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, SLCE.LicensingStatus.UserNotAuthorized.ToString());                  
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion      

}
```

Implemented a custom Beahavior to handle the exceptions.

```
public class LicensingBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{

    protected override void AddServerErrorHandlers(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        int errorHandlerCount = endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Count;
        base.AddServerErrorHandlers(endpoint, endpointDispatcher);
        IErrorHandler webHttpErrorHandler = endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers[errorHandlerCount];
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.RemoveAt(errorHandlerCount);
        RestErrorHandler newHandler = new RestErrorHandler(webHttpErrorHandler,DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat);
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(newHandler);
    }        

}
```

Then implemented the IErrorhandler to send the status code and description if the Authorization or authentication fails.

```
public class RestErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    IErrorHandler _originalErrorHandler;
    WebMessageFormat _format;
    public RestErrorHandler(IErrorHandler originalErrorHandler,WebMessageFormat format)
    {
        this._originalErrorHandler = originalErrorHandler;
        this._format = format;
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        return error is WebProtocolException;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        WebProtocolException licensingException = error as WebProtocolException;
        if (licensingException != null)
        {

            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, null, new ValidationErrorBodyWriter(licensingException));
            if (_format == WebMessageFormat.Json)
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty prop = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                prop.StatusCode = licensingException.StatusCode;
                prop.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, prop);
                fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));
            }
            else if(_format == WebMessageFormat.Xml)
            {
                HttpResponseMessageProperty prop = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                prop.StatusCode = licensingException.StatusCode;
                prop.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
                fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, prop);
                fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Xml));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this._originalErrorHandler.ProvideFault(error, version, ref fault);
        }
    }

    class ValidationErrorBodyWriter : BodyWriter
    {
        private WebProtocolException validationException;
        Encoding utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

        public ValidationErrorBodyWriter(WebProtocolException validationException)
            : base(true)
        {
            this.validationException = validationException;
        }

        protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("root");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "object");

            writer.WriteStartElement("StatusCode");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "string");
            writer.WriteString(this.validationException.StatusCode.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("Description");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "string");
            writer.WriteString(this.validationException.StatusDescription);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at Azure Storage REST api security documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179428.aspx) to get a fair idea about how MS has designed security around their API.
Most of the REST API i have seen use a API token based approach where these tokens are passed along each request to identify the caller. 
Also look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service)