# Amend PHP code to use TLS rather than SSL

Tags: php, ssl

I have a bespoke payment system that uses PHP to send a buyer through to Barclays EPDQ to make a payment. EPDQ no longer supports SSL so I have to convert it to use TLS.

Looking at the page, it seems to me there is only a small block of code that needs editing
I'm out of my depth here, can anyone suggest the changes I should make? Or is it not as simpel as I assume?

Here's the bit I think needs editing:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://" . $requesthost . $requestdocument);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestbody);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        $responsedata = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: TLS is essentially SSL 3.1, it's just a name change. Do you have any indicator that your code is in fact *not* using TLS?

Comment: No, just a note form EPDQ letting me know that 
"We will no longer be supporting any version of SSL encryption."

Comment: Is there anyway I can check?

Comment: I don't know, looking at the documentation there doesn't appear to be an API to check for this. SSL/TLS is a negotiated protocol in which both sides will use the newest version of the protocol available to both. If you have a reasonably recent version of the curl library built in, this should not be a concern. You could try `curl -v https://google.com` on the command line; even though PHP's curl version may be different, it's an indicator of what curl you have installed and what SSL/TLS version it'll use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1' to your PPHttpConfig.php.

and

curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1); in your code

originaly from [SSL error can not change to TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759383/ssl-error-can-not-change-to-tls) and [PHP Curl (with NSS) is probably using SSLv3 insted of TLS when connecting to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452755/php-curl-is-probably-using-sslv3-insted-of-tls-when-connecting-to-http)

Answer (score 0):

You need few more parameters in your code.

You must also set 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' to 'true'.

You can read more about the [cacert.crt here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and get one. Make sure you read the terms of use.

Yes, you need all the options in order to achieve maximum forward secrecy.

You can read more about the TLS security and implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586357/how-to-secure-a-restful-php-web-service-with-ssl-tls-and-or-message-level-securi/33225727#33225727).

Below is explained what each option does.

```
/** 
 * 
 * Start Fix SSLv3/TLS connectivity problems
 * 
 * CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER prevent MITM attacks
 * WARNING: Disabling this would prevent curl from detecting Man-in-the-middle (MITM) attack
 * 
 */

/**
 * @param CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
 * 
 * FALSE to stop CURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
 * Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.
 * CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST may also need to be TRUE or FALSE if CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is disabled (it defaults to 2).
 * Setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to 2 (This is the default value) will garantee that the certificate being presented to you have a 'common name' matching the URN you are using to access the remote resource.
 * This is a healthy check but it doesn't guarantee your program is not being decieved.
 * 
 */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

/**
 *  
 * @param CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST
 * 
 * Check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate.
 * Check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided.
 * 
 * @value 1 to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate. 
 * @value 2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided.
 * In production environments the value of this option should be kept at 2 (default value).
 * Support for value 1 removed in cURL 7.28.1 
 */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

/**
 * 
 * Force use of TLS
 * 
 */

    /**
     *
     * Let's explain the magic of comparing your TLS certificate to the verified CA Authorities and how does that affect MITM attacks
     *  
     * Man in the middle (MITM)
     * Your program could be misleaded into talking to another server instead. This can be achieved through several mechanisms, like dns or arp poisoning.
     * The intruder can also self-sign a certificate with the same 'comon name' your program is expecting. 
     * The communication would still be encrypted but you would be giving away your secrets to an impostor.
     * This kind of attack is called 'man-in-the-middle'
     * Defeating the 'man-in-the-middle'
     * We need to to verify the certificate being presented to us is good for real. We do this by comparing it against a certificate we reasonable* trust.
     * If the remote resource is protected by a certificate issued by one of the main CA's like Verisign, GeoTrust et al, you can safely compare against Mozilla's CA certificate bundle, 
     * which you can get from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
     *
     */
    //TODO: If TLSv1_1 found insecure and/or unreliable change to TLSv1_1 or TLS1_2
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2); // CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1; CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2

    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) == 'WIN') {
        $crt = substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos( __FILE__, '\\'))."\crt\cacert.crt"; // WIN
    }
    else {
        $crt = str_replace('\\', '/', substr(__FILE__, 0, strrpos( __FILE__, '/')))."/crt/cacert.crt"; // *NIX
    }

    // The cert path is relative to this file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $crt); // Set the location of the CA-bundle

    /** 
     * Fix Error: 35 - Unknown SSL protocol error in connections
     * 
     * Improve maximum forward secrecy
     */
    // Please keep in mind that this list has been checked against the SSL Labs' WEAK ciphers list in 2014.
    $arrayCiphers = array(
    'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA',
    'DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA',
    'AES256-SHA',
    'ADH-AES256-SHA',
    'KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA',
    'EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA',
    'EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA',
    'DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA',
    'DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA',
    'ADH-AES128-SHA',
    'AES128-SHA',
    'KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA',
    'EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA',
    'EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA',
    'EXP-KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA',
    'EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA',
    'EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA',
    'EXP-DES-CBC-SHA'
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, implode(':', $arrayCiphers));
```

Let me know, if you have any other questions, I will try to answer.