# how to solve error SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: magento

community/AW_Blog: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in magento blog aheadwork instalation

Comment: How ancient is that AheadWorks 3rd party module? Sounds like a curl transaction was hardcoded to use SSL V3 instead of negotiating for a compatible connection. Sounds like you need to contact them for an upgrade.

Comment: i have already upgrade version and i find that error while install any extention in magento connect manager please help me if u have solution

Comment: Sorry, didn't connect `AheadWork installation' with Magento Connect. Related issue over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759383/ssl-error-can-not-change-to-tls

Comment: Does Magento plan on addressing this server-side? Apparently becoming a common problem. Not sure if it only affects 1.9.1.0 or additional versions but I've experienced it twice now, with two different extensions on two different environments. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58421/strange-error-when-installing-extension-over-magento-connect/58422#58422

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that Magento finally got around to Poodle fixes and disabled **SSLV3** on Magento Connect. But in a left-hand, right-hand disconnect type thing, forgot that the `downloader/` software they provide has **SSLV3** issues in some curl requests it uses and didn't provide a patch.

`downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php` is the affected file and a `curl` request needs to be modified to request TLS. The lines look something like this:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

Add your own curl option for TLSV1 as follows:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

Note that this isn't in `app/core` or `lib`, but over in `downloader/lib`

Comment: So if somebody knows how to write a module to patch stuff in `downloader\lib`, please feel free to explain it instead of a useless "don't modify core files" comment. Also, "don't use connect" isn't a valid comment as some modules are only available through command line `mage` for me **to download them for manual install**.

Answer (score 2):

This is an error related to Magento Connect updating their server to not allow SSLV3, but Magento still trying to use it to connect. I have just built a fix. You can download it here: https://www.dwdonline.com/blog/fix-magento-error14077410ssl-routinesssl23_get_server_hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure.html. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had a client running PHP 5.4 on Windows Server 2003, which uses OpenSSL 0.9.8zf at the time of writing. I upgraded to OpenSSL 1.0.1p by downloading the latest files and replacing libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in the PHP root directory. This seems to have resolved my particular issue.

Comment: He has already accepted an answer, so posting this makes no sense

Comment: Merely sharing information I hope others find useful. This post is the top search result for these keywords, but his answer did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had PHP 5.3.5 which came with OPENSSL 0.9.8 and I had same issue.
Upgraded to PHP 7, which came with updated version of OPENSSL fixed the problem.