# Magento Community Edition 1.9.2 Update failed - Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1

Tags: magento

Today I did an upgrade to version 1.9.2.0 so that patch SUPEE-6285 also is installed, but halfway the installation (With Magento connect) the console showed an error screen similar to wat you see when the maintenance.flag file is in your root (503 error). The maintenance.flag was indeed in the root, but very strange that it showed up in the console.

After removing the maintenance.flag the site stayed blank, also the admin page. I can access the connect manager, but everything I want to install with the extension manager fails with this message "CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default failed: Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1"

How to fix this? If I look in the files, half of the files have the date of today and the other half an older date, so it looks to me that the installation broke down or something

Answer (score 7):

In the file `downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php` Change the code

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

to

```
if(isset($var)){$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');}
```

and problem will be solve for now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622558/how-to-solve-error-ssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure/28649569#28649569), the Magento Connect subsystem attempts to fire up `curl` and use an SSL connection which has apparently not been disabled on all the Magento servers as you did have a partially successful upgrade.

[As noted here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73748/magento-1-9-2-unknown-cipher-in-list-tlsv1) and the previous link, the fix is to enable TLSv1 by editing `downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php` to include the line:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

We ran into the issue back in February when Magento de-Poodlized the servers.

Note: links are all Stack Exchange questions related to the issue in this section (StackOverflow) and Magento.StackExchange

Answer (score 0):

I went to the file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php and find out there was a line with TLSv1 in it, so i put // in front of it and that solved the problem! Now i can do updates with connect!

But....

Now my site shows up with links that are not working and my admin stays blank...

Next problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated Magento to 1.9.2, you may encounter this error when using the downloader. The problem is due to older ciphers and remains an uncorrected bug. But this is fixed by adjusting one line of code.

To correct this, in downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php, change:

**$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');**

to

**$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);**