# magento admin page blank after upgrade

Tags: magento

I had a lot of problems with upgrading to 9.2, see [Magento Community Edition 1.9.2 Update failed - Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290475/magento-community-edition-1-9-2-update-failed-unknown-cipher-in-list-tlsv1/31311009#31311009)

I solved that problem but now my site shows up the logo and links, but no style (CSS?). Also the links are not working, they redirect to index.php and my admin page is blank and not accesable due to this.

Comment: Regarding the css, check that your app/etc/local.xml is pointing to the right place, for the index.php it could be a problem with your htaccess file, try to use your original one. Flush cache and reindex

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Answer (score 4):

I have experieced the same issue. After spending a couple of days the issue has been identified.

I've tried to upgrade Magento 1.7.x to 1.9.x then I got blank admin page.

**Fix**

1. Download Magento 1.9.x mirror: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror
2. Remove /skin/adminhtml from your current installation and replace with [this](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.9/skin/adminhtml/default/default).
3. Remove /app/design/adminhtml from your current installation and replace with [this](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/magento-1.9/app/design/adminhtml/default/default).

This fixed the blank admin page issue.

I hope this helps.

Comment: worked for me...I would add, if you still are experiencing issues you can delete/change file name of `var` directory in root.