# Magento blank admin pages

Tags: php, magento

Some background information:

We developped a website in magento and it runs just fine on our server. Now we need to transfer the website, but as soon as we copied the database and all files to the new server we had some problems. The website seems to run just fine but when we login with the same login information as before all of the admin pages are blank. we can see the admin bar on top but not the content.

This site isn't live on the new server since we just changed the .hosts file in order to see the site.

I tried a lot things all around the internet but none of that seems to work.

What could couse this problem and how can we fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [magento admin page blank after upgrade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311072/magento-admin-page-blank-after-upgrade)

Comment: i had this also and resolved them to delete all cookies from the given host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution.

i added these lines to my index.php file in order to see logs of the problem.

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Then i saw some error loggings on the admin page telling me there was a problem with CURL.

So i want to my php.ini file and i saw that CURL wasn't enabled there. So enabeling this did the trick.