# Force PHP to use TLS 1.0 instead of SSL

Tags: php, ssl

Good day all.
I'm using a payment gateway on a site with a credit card payments, the bank gateway send to all its customers that it will stop all SSL connections starting from the 3rd of January, so I must be sure to doing the right things without tests.

actually I'm using this configuration just before making the connection:

```
<?php
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$to_url); 
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
?>
```

this is set to false due to debugging needs.

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

So, I've read that adding:

```
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 1
```

should force the use of TLS, is that true?
Does adding this option will prevent the gateway to ignore my requests?
Does it needs some other options?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to do anything - as long as there's some version supported by both the server and curl it will work. The SSL/TLS handshake process involves exchanging information about what each peer supports.

Comment: that sound really confortable, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might experience connectivity issues, if you don't specify your TLS version, which often happens.

You need the following options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cacert.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, $array_ciphers);
```

This way, you will achieve maximum forward secrecy.

You can always remove any of the mentioned parameters, but before you do, make sure you read this [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586357/how-to-secure-a-restful-php-web-service-with-ssl-tls-and-or-message-level-securi/33225727#33225727) of the functions above.
Afterwards you can decide what you would like to do.

Let me know, if you have any questions.