# Creating a web API using WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, api, ssl

I was assigned to design and develop an API which will expose our
   functionality over the web, I am fairly new to this, so I got some questions...

The Requests

1. The API should support clients from all sorts of platforms and
       programming languages (may include some propriety platforms/devices)
2. The API will be exposed to paying clients and secured by SSL (this
       is a must, money is invloved)
3. Our code is in .NET, so WCF should be used.

After some research around the web I'm thinking about the following solution:

1. Exposing the methods through POST/GET (other bindings if needed)
2. For additional client identification and Authorization password and username will be sent as parameters.
3. Should I use WCF Web API, or is it unnecessary?

In the article [Exposing WCF API - Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service), I read that if the channel is SSL secured, then simple username/password is the simplest way for Authorization purposes

I don't know if I should elaborate and explain more, but am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a reason why you shouldn't use WCF. You should have look at WCF REST programming model too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.