# Securing rest service

Tags: security, rest, ssl, sha, digest

I’m designing a REST service that needs to be well secured against unauthorized access. I’m thinking about requiring a security digest that’s generated by hashing all request parameters plus a secret key with sha-256 and making the service only available over https. Can anyone tell me if this is sufficient security?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practices for securing a REST API / web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service)

Comment: "sufficent" is a relative term. [There are trade-off that you need to consider given the value of what you are protecting](http://prezi.com/7gi-uyhtwwiq/information-security-aspects-for-message-exchange/).

Comment: @Tom: Thank you. That’s a very helpful presentation.
Privacy sensitive customer data from different third parties would be submitted to the service, which is why I want to use SSL. I thought about using a digest in combination with SSL to handle authentication and ensure the message integrity.  The combination would be pretty secure (to use another relative term) and still not too hard for the different clients to implement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are using en [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), not a plain SHA-256 to generate the "security digest".

Next, what are you going to put into the input of this digest? You'll want to have at least the method, the URI, the payload, and very possibly most of the headers of the request (there are many headers that affect the meaning of an HTTP request that are important in a REST context). That might be difficult depending on what HTTP client you are using because the client might set or change headers in a way that you do not directly control.

Finally, where are you going to put this digest? A custom header (e.g. `X-Request-Authenticator`) seems sensible, or maybe a cookie if the client is running in a web browser.

I would recommend using existing tools if you can, instead of creating something yourself. Using SSL already gives you message integrity protection so start with that. Then, if you just need simple access control, HTTP basic auth will work just fine with a REST request. Or you could have the client present a certificate and verify it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to HMAC, I wasn’t aware of that.
I had thought to put the digest in the message body, together with the request parameters, in a basic xml format. The API is only for server to server communication. I saw that in the Amazon( http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) S3 implementation it was put in a header as well, but I don’t understand what the advantage of that is.
Do I understand you correctly that you think using SSL in combination with a security hash is overkill?

Comment: You can't put the digest in the body and still maintain the REST property. For one, methods like GET and DELETE don't have a body, and in PUT requests, the body should represent the object that is intended to be stored at the address designated by the URI, and nothing more (or less). The message authentication digest is not conceptually part of that object. As for SSL plus the hash being overkill, yes, you understand me correctly: the message integrity protection is already provided by SSL, and it is left to you only to decide whether to allow or disallow the request (based on authentication).