# public/private rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a REST JSON Api in Node.js with the Express.js framework. For authentication I use HTTP basic. This is my code so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

// Http basic auth.

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.search('Basic ') === 0){
    var header = new Buffer(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1], 'base64').toString();
    var headerSplit = header.split(':');
    var username = headerSplit[0];
    var password = headerSplit[1];

    if(username && password && (username.length >= 4 && password.length >= 2){
        if(auth(username, password)){
          next(); return;
        } else {
          res.send('Authentication required', 401);
        }
    }
  } else {
    res.header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Login with username/password"');
    res.send('Authentication required', 401);
  }
});

// Public
app.post('/restore-password', function(req, res){
});

// Public
app.get('/search', function(req, res){
});

// Public
app.post('/users', function(req, res){
});

// Private
app.get('/user', function(req, res){
});

// Private
app.get('/protected-data', function(req, res){
});
```

How could I properly seperate public and private functions in my REST api? I hope my question is clear.

Thanks for help.

Comment: @helmus ... call it what you want, I call it functions, my bike has functions, my api too, what a useless comment.

Comment: sorry didn't meant to be rude, just wanna keep things clear, check out this thread for possibly more adequate info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service

Comment: @onlineracoon What do you mean by public/private? And what exactly you want to seperate?

Comment: @freakish I mean, when users login they have access to "private" functionality of the API, when users are not logged in they can only do certain things (login, signup, restore-password etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `app.use` because it adds the middleware to **all** routes. Define your authentication handler like this:

```
function authentication_required(req, res, next){
    // The other authentication code goes here.
};
```

And now in every route you can do (for example) this:

```
// Public
app.post("/restore-password", function(req, res) {
    console.log( "No need for authentication!" );
});

// Private (add authentication_required middleware to the route)
app.get("/settings", authentication_required, function(req, res) {
    console.log( "I'm authenticated, so I can read this!" );
});
```