# RESTful approach to user authentication

Tags: rest

I am writing a simple authentication service and am curious as to the best way to do a get user by username and password scenario.

For instance

/users?username=foo&password=bar

Currently, it just returns the representation of the user which would be the equivalent of

/users/{id}

And that returns a 200

But I was thinking to myself that I could leverage caching more if I made it so the first request just returns a 303 with a location header to /users/10

This way, I can effectively cache the result of the call in /users/10 but not cache /users?username=foo&password=bar, as that wouldn't be appropriate to cache.

It feels more "HTTP" to me, but obviously it requires another HTTP call for a client; which approach is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Good idea to have a quick look to the best practices regarding securing (authentication) of REST calls. A good place to look at, is this older stackoverflow discussion thread:

[Best Practices for securing a REST API / web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service)