# How do I handle authentication for a REST service?

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, authorization

When I am writing a web service that needs authentication, I usually have to choose between two options:

1. I can have a dedicated authentication call that creates a session. All subsequent calls are authenticated over a cookie. This is exactly how you would do authentication in a classic web site. This is not hard to write, but is not stateless.
2. I can send authentication information (such as credentials, a token, whatever) on each single request. This way it's stateless, but there is more overhead.

Are there suggested best practices which way you should go? Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practices for securing a REST API / web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service)