# REST: How to transfer authorization key to server?

Tags: http, authorization

What is a good way to transfer an authorization key to a server? I'm building an REST-API right now and I'm stuck how the user can authorize on that api. He will get an authorization key (thats not the problem), but what would be a good way to pass this key to the server? As a GET parameter, as an HTTP Header field, as a cookie?

Which way is easy to handle with most of programming languages (e.g. I want to use the API with php or ajax..)

Comment: HTTP header seems the best.

Comment: I've heard that some proxies/servers strip a http header field down when they don't know it..

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to send via HTTP POST, and if possible then encrypt it before sending it and decrypt it on server on need basis

Comment: In order to use the api you have to transfer the key with every request to the server. What if you just want to get some information? In this way I have to use everytime HTTP POST. This seems wrong, doesn't it?

Comment: well an attacker can also attack on cookie as well as header and HTTP request data. so in this sense neither way is 100% secure, what you can do is to encrypt your key before saving it in cookie and decrypt it on server after fetching it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [HTTP Basic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) authentication scheme, which uses the `Authorization` HTTP header. With Basic authentication, the client must provide its credentials on each request. so you might prefer the [Digest](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) authentication scheme, which is a little more secure.

Without more details, I might recommend [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) with the *Client Credentials* grant type. Basically, the client uses Basic authentication with its client credentials *once* to receive an access token, and then it uses the access token on subsequent resource requests. Typically the access token is submitted using the `Authorization` HTTP header.

OAuth is really an *authorization* framework, but it provides a good solution for API *authentication* also, and you might find its authorization tools useful for securing access to API resources. It could be that the *Authorization Code* grant type is applicable to your use case as well.

Related: [Best Practices for securing a REST API / web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service?rq=1)