# How to secure JSON files against another websites

Tags: php, android, iphone, json, security

I have JSON file on my server(on my website).My Iphone and Android app use this JSON.
I would like to hide or secure json files from another websites or app.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You can try to use some .htaccess file to restrict the access, you can add some code... however a determined hacker can one way or another obtain this file.

Comment: have you tried anything or googled anything ?

Comment: @romain did my answer helped to clarify what you asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to do this it´s by using a Token that signs every WS call.

You can generate this Token in many ways, the most extended it´s by password username encryption.

Users in App sends USER/PASSWORD by SSL secured connection to the server.

Server validates USER/PASSWORD and sends back a token that will be used to sign every call made now on, so the user doesn't have to be sending every time the USER/PASSWORD info.

You can also check how to secure your web service following this SO link.

> [Best Practices for securing a REST API / web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service)

Hope it helps. :)