# REST Authentication best practice

Tags: rest

How to provide authentication for an user who via a screen logs in to my application that uses REST Services, is servlet filter the best practice ? I have already implemented Oauth for the applictions that need access to REST services.
This is specifically for user as a client,  not application as a client. One application instance can have multiple users. OAuth typically deals with application as client.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practices for securing a REST API / web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a username and an encrypted key in POST parameters or appended in the URL (GET) for authorization.