# How to connect Spring boot application to Android client

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot

I have a layered spring boot project(backend) and i want to connect it to an android app client(frontend) to take input and show output, where do i have to start? Is it an HTTP connection or i need to configure the spring boot application? Both backend and frontend are localhost. I'm using java.

Comment: Start by reading the Andorid documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Practices for securing a REST API / web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service)

Answer (score 4):

The usual architecture is following:

- `Spring boot application` is the **server** - it listens for `requests` from clients and answers them with `responses`
- `Android app`, `web app`, etc. is the **client** - it sends `requests` to server and processes the `responses`

The structure of the requests and responses is called an **API (Application programming interface)**. You may develop your own API from scratch or better follow a standard - e.g. [`REST API`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YcW25PHnAA).

Example (when using REST API):

- User in the android app (client) clicks on *Show todos* button.
- The android app sends an HTTP request to the server: `GET /todos`
- The server (spring boot app) responds with HTTP response containing a list of todos in JSON format:

```
[
    {
        name: "Buy groceries"
        done: false
    },
    {
        name: "Paint house"
        done: true
    },
    ...
]
```

- The android app parses this response (usually by using a library) and displays it to the user through some user interface elements.

So it's probably best to start with the server part in my opinion, you can easily test it in the browser or using generic HTTP client like `Postman`. *Spring* has very good documentation also with beginner guides like this one: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ which will get you started quickly.